# Update a table from a union select statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables as below:

**tablea**

```
 k |  1    | 2 
--------------------
 a | mango | xx
 b | orange| xx
 c | xx    | apple
 d | xx    | banana
 a | xx    | mango
```

**tableb**

```
 k |  1    | 2 
--------------------
 a |       | 
 b |       |  
 c |       |  
 d |       |
```

How can I update `tableb` from `tablea` so I get the results below?

tableb

```
 k |  1    | 2 
--------------------
 a | mango | mango
 b | orange| xx
 c | xx    | apple
 d | xx    | banana
```

if in case I try to use a update statement like below

```
update tableb 
set 1 = x.1,
    2 = x.2
from 
 (
    select * from tablea
) x 
where tablea.k = x.k
```

Can I make the update statement to ignore `xx` if `k` is duplicate?

Thanks.

Comment: how to determine that row1 (`k='a'`) will be `mango, mango` not `xx,xx` or `mango,xx`?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach  I was hopping `xx` mean `null`? But yes, we need more information.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza if `xx` means `null` then I will ask if `tablea` have another row `a | orange | banana` then what should `tableb` be. `Taz` your question need more logic about data in `tablea` and how to update `tableb`

Comment: hi 'xx' are just two characters(some thing like 'N/A'). in tablea, there is a big backend calculation behind that finally brings me only these 5 rows. I won't be getting an answer like 'a | orange | banana'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SELECT, hope you can make the update.

1. Try to search a match for every one on the left side with name <> 'xx'
2. Then union with the rest of rows I havent use it yet.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a3a6f)**

```
SELECT t1."k", t1."1", COALESCE(t2."2", 'xx') "2"
FROM tablea t1
LEFT JOIN tablea t2
       ON  t1."1" = t2."2"
WHERE t1."1" <> 'xx'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1."k", t1."1", t1."2"
FROM tablea t1
WHERE t1."1" = 'xx'
  AND t1."2" NOT IN (SELECT t2."1" FROM tablea t2 WHERE t2."1" <> 'xx')
```